# What is the difference between unary relations and one-element relations?

Tags: relations, universal-algebra

My question is exactly like in the title: What is the difference between **unary relations** and **one-element relations**?

If I start with definitions, given a set $X$ **unary relation $\theta$** is a subset of $X$ (while n-ary relation would be a subset of $X^n$ of course). So for every $a \in X$, we would have $a \in \theta$.

Then, a **one-element relation $\phi$** would be what? Is it a subset of $X^n$, but relating only one element with itself?

I couldn´t find any sources for this.

It would help to see some examples of such relations, let´s say on a set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A relation is a set and so a one-element relation is a one-element set.

Comment: @Wuestenfux So an example of one-element relation would be just one number, like $1$ or $2$ on $\mathbb{N}$? While an unary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ would be for example $a \theta a$ iff $a = a$?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of where the terminology "one-element relation" occurs?

Comment: You can have a binary relation $R$ defined on the the integers by $xRy$ if $(x,y)=(1,2)$. That's a one element relation. A unary relation is a relation that takes one element as an argument. So the even numbers form a unary relation on the integers.